# Does Paypal PayFlow Pro API available for Sweden?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

Does Paypal PayFlow Pro API available for Sweden?if yes, then how much it charges to use in sweden?

Answer (score 1):

[Payflow](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-gateway/)  is only available for United States, Australia, Canada & New Zealand